# Best practice for connecting to a vpn though docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, openvpn

Some apps we have depend on being connected to our VPN to connect to different (not-yet dockerized)solutions.

What is the 'docker way' of doing this? In my mind adding OpenVPN to an existing image is against the docker philosophy.

From where I'm standing I feel that creating a docker VPN client container makes the most sense. But what would that look like? I use docker compose, so there would definitely be a

```
myContainer
- links: myVPNClient
```

but would I then have to forward ports? Or what would have to happen to enable `myContainer` to connect **through** the openVPN container.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Another option would be to ask [Jess Frazelle (`jfrazelle`)](https://github.com/jfrazelle), who is in the habit of [containerizing everything](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34721353/6309).

Sure enough, she has a [`jfrazelle/dockerfiles/openvpn`](https://github.com/jfrazelle/dockerfiles/tree/master/openvpn) project which exposes it directly to the host:

```
vpn:
  build: .
  volumes:
    - .:/etc/openvpn
  net: host
  devices:
    - /dev/net/tun:/dev/net/tun
  cap_add:
    - NET_ADMIN
```

It uses a [TUN (not TAP) interface](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/BridgingAndRouting).

Comment: I'm still getting errors, in my .opvn file I'm copying my .crt files and .key file into /etc/openvpn/.
Then I get this error on run:
jono@JonosMacbookPro:~/projects/hobvpn-client% docker-compose run vpn hobnob.opvn                                                          [16:03:04]
Options error: --ca fails with 'ca.crt': No such file or directory
Options error: --cert fails with 'local.crt': No such file or directory
Options error: --key fails with 'local.key': No such file or directory
Options error: Please correct these errors.

Comment: It would be best to ask a separate question to address those errors.

Answer (score 6):

Probably the easiest solution would be to configure any containers that need the vpn to use the network namespace of the vpn container.  That is, your docker-compose.yml would include something like:

```
vpn:
  image: myvpn_image

app1:
  image: app1_image
  net: container:vpn
```

With this configuration, the `vpn` container and the `app1` container see the same network evironment.